# are multiple WordPress cron instances redundant and what would have caused this?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am working with WordPress cron for the first time, and understand that this is called from `wp-cron.php` and references a table called `wp_options` which in turn references a row where

```
option_name='cron'
```

The data for field `option_value` is serialized PHP array.  I notice a lot of redundant instances of the same job, and wonder if this is a mistake and if these can be deleted.

Also, what might have caused this?

[image: repeased "sm_ping" job]

Answer (score 0):

I already face it.
It cause site slow in functioning. If for same job multiple cron was created then you must have to delete it.
You can delete it by using the [WP Crontrol plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/).